# Selectively deleting duplicates from table based on field value in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table (ID column exists but not shown below) :

| Email | Course | DateComplete |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1@1.com | Running | 01/01/2021 |
| 1@1.com | Running |  |
| 1@1.com | Running |  |
| 2@2.com | Walking |  |
| 2@2.com | Walking |  |
| 2@2.com | Walking |  |

I'd like to know if it is possible to delete all duplicate (of Email&Course) records from my table, but also ensuring that no records with a value in DateComplete are deleted.

So after running the query I would have :

| Email | Course | DateComplete |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1@1.com | Running | 01/01/2021 |
| 2@2.com | Walking |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a query with an aggregation such as

```
SELECT Email, Course, MAX(DateComplete) AS DateComplete
  INTO [dbo].[new_table]
  FROM [dbo].[current_table]
 GROUP BY Email, Course
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop that deletes the dupes:

```vb
Public Function DeleteDupes()

    Const Sql   As String = "Select * From Course Order By Email, Course, DateComplete Desc"
    
    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Values  As String
    
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)
    
    While Not Records.EOF
        If Values <> Records!Email.Value & Records!Course.Value Then
            Values = Records!Email.Value & Records!Course.Value
        Else
            Records.Delete
        End If
        Records.MoveNext
    Wend
    Records.Close
    
End Function
```